# Python Adding Explicit Tag to MP3

Tags: python, mp3, id3, mutagen

I am working on using python to add an explicit tag into my mp3s. My kids are getting older and I would like to share some music with them, but it would probably be best not to share the ones with naughty words. So I wrote up a python script to read through the lyrics, USLT tag, if available and compare to a list.  All works fairly well. 
My question is where does the tag go?  Based on ID3 standard, there does not seem to be a place for this. Most info online points to using ITunes to convert to m4a file and use the CONTENTADVISORY tag, which does not seem standard. I can use mutagen to add in a tag but I not sure where I would put it.  Would it be a custom tag under the TXXX and how is the best way to add those so players like ITunes can pick that up.  My hope was to use the tag in smart playlists for filtering.  Thanks.

Code Example:

```
def search_files(src_path):
for root, _, filenames in os.walk(src_path):
    for files in filenames:
        explicit= False
        if files.endswith('.mp3'):
            audio = ID3(os.path.join(root, files))
            for key in audio:
                if key.startswith("USLT"):
                    explicit = explict_check(audio[key].text)
                    break

            if explicit:
                #audio["TXXX"] = ???XX
                print audio["TIT2"].text, "Explicit"
```

Comment: The tags are 2.x in version. Based on the ID3 wiki I did not see content advisory as an existing tag. which made me think it needed to be added as custom, but not sure if other players will read that or not.